# How to use Linq query Result in OrderBy?

Tags: c#, linq

Here i had scenario to get the data  in date wise of this month(Present month)

```
Excepted Result
     Date_time        sum(collection.amountreceived )  Sum(bank_deposit.depositamount)
       1/07/2014                 2000                 1000
       2/07/2014                 3000                 3000
```

Schema

```
bank_deposit

   agentid         (nvarchar(30))   
   depositamount   (DECIMAL(10,0))    
   date_time       (TIMESTAMP)

collection

   customeridn       (varchar(30))
   amountreceived    (DECIMAL(10,0))
   date_time         (TIMESTAMP)  
   agentid           (nvarchar(30))
```

Here I used union to get the datetime column data in one column

```
 var unionDateColumn = ((from agent in db.collections select agent.Date_Time)
        .Union(from u in db.bank_deposit select u.Date_Time)).ToList();
```

How can i use this unionDateColumn  data for orderby and to get expected output?

Below is query for sum of amount but here my issue is how to

```
var model = (from coll in db.collections.Where(e => e.AgentID == item.AgentID)
                          let depositedAmount = db.bank_deposit.Where(d => d.AgentID == item.AgentID ).Sum(c => c.DepositedAmount) == null ? 0
                          : db.bank_deposit.Where(d => d.AgentID == item.AgentID).Sum(x => x.DepositedAmount)
                          let collectionAmount = db.collections.Where(c => c.AgentID == item.AgentID).Sum(c => c.AmountReceived) == null ? 0
                          : db.collections.Where(v => v.AgentID == item.AgentID).Sum(m => m.AmountReceived)
                          select new GetBalanceAmount
                          {
                              DepositedAmount = depositedAmount,
                                 CollectionAmount = collectionAmount
                          });
```

Comment: i had two table both tables having duplicate data so i used here union for date_time field now unionDateColumn query  returing the date for two columns (this is dynamic columns) by using this column how to do orderby clause with below model query to get expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to order the result by date_time

```
var result = unoinDateColumn.OrderBy(t=>t.Date_Time).ToList().;
```

Comment: no, i want to order by the unoinDateColumn it returning the dates of two columns please see my expected output

Comment: model.ToList().OrderByDescending(unoinDateColumn).FirstOrDefault(); i tried like this

Answer (score 0):

Why FirstOrDefault ? i asume you want every row.

Sajeetharan's example:
var result = unoinDateColumn.OrderBy(t=>t.Date_Time).ToList();
result is the same as "select * from unionDateColumn order by DateTime"

Your example:
model.ToList().OrderByDescending(unoinDateColumn).FirstOrDefault();

is the same as "Select * from model orderby unionDateColumn"
May i ask why you are handling each column seperately? insted of in one large array ?

Handle it in one array, and do like this model.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date_Time);

it will affect the object model and order it like this model = model.sortedBy(model.Date_Time);

Comment: no magic-mouse ur didnt get my point could you plese give one example to get my expected result & by using with my schema